# Using file aliases inside an Android APK?

Tags: android, alias, symlink, apk

Is it possible to us file aliases within an Android APK?

For example, I have the same file that I wish to reference using `R.drawable.icon_name,` and I am using the same icon for hdpi, ldpi, and mdpi. Is it possible to use file aliases/ symlinks to have the icon in `/res/hdpi/` and create aliases in `/res/mdpi/` and `/res/ldpi/` pointing to that file, or is there a better approach altogether?

Comment: Just put those in /res/drawable and it will become density independent.

Comment: So even though that folder does not exist, I can make it and reference them there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use file aliases/ symlinks to have the icon in /res/hdpi/ and create aliases in /res/mdpi/ and /res/ldpi/ pointing to that file

There are [alias resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources) that you can use.

Comment: Ah, that's pretty neat. I knew that it was possible with strings, but didn't know I could use bitmap images as well.